# Select the rows with max priority for each category where priority is assigned using a case statement

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

Consider the following table

`Designation(empPosMapId, empName, designation, department, job description, dateassigned)`

Designation can be "JUNIOR","SENIOR" and "DIRECTOR" and departments can be one of many departments. 
If department is not mentioned, it means the person is holding the specified designation for all departments

There can be multiple persons holding same role in each department. Also, a single person can hold more than one role per department.

Sample Data

```
empPosId| empName | designation | department | desc  | date
--------|---------|-------------|------------|-------|-------------
1       | per1    | DIRECTOR    | dept1      | blah1 | 2015-12-23
2       | per1    | SENIOR      | (NULL)     | blah1 | 2015-12-23
3       | per1    | JUNIOR      | dept2      | blah1 | 2015-12-23
4       | per2    | SENIOR      | dept1      | blah1 | 2015-12-23
5       | per2    | JUNIOR      | (NULL)     | blah1 | 2015-12-23
6       | per3    | DIRECTOR    | (NULL)     | blah1 | 2015-12-23
7       | per4    | JUNIOR      | dept2      | blah1 | 2015-12-23
```

The designations are ranked JUNIOR < SENIOR < DIRECTOR
Also, roles specific to a department overrides an overall role. (ie., per1 has overall role of SENIOR but is DIRECTOR for dept1 hence wrt dept1 per1 will be DIRECTOR

I need a query to fetch the details of highest designation each person is holding given a department.

ie., for dept1

```
empPosId| empName | designation | department | desc  | date
--------|---------|-------------|------------|-------|-------------
1       | per1    | DIRECTOR    | dept1      | blah1 | 2015-12-23
4       | per2    | SENIOR      | dept1      | blah1 | 2015-12-23
6       | per3    | DIRECTOR    | (NULL)     | blah1 | 2015-12-23
```

Similarly for dept2,

```
empPosId| empName | designation | department | desc  | date
--------|---------|-------------|------------|-------|-----------
2       | per1    | SENIOR      | (NULL)     | blah1 | 2015-12-23
5       | per2    | JUNIOR      | (NULL)     | blah1 | 2015-12-23
6       | per3    | DIRECTOR    | (NULL)     | blah1 | 2015-12-23
7       | per4    | JUNIOR      | dept2      | blah1 | 2015-12-23
```

I have a working query that uses case statement to determine the highest designation by assigning numbers and picking the row that got highest number. 
The issue is that its too big and i need to get it simplified and use it in hibernate :|

(Assuming deptInput is the department of interest to the user)

```sql
select * from Designation where empPosId in (
    select a.empPosId from (
        select *, case 
            WHEN department=<deptInput> THEN 4 
            WHEN department is NULL AND DESIGNATION = "DIRECTOR" THEN 3 
            WHEN department is NULL AND DESIGNATION = "SENIOR" THEN 2
            WHEN department is NULL AND DESIGNATION = "JUNIOR" THEN 1
            ELSE 0 END AS "priority"
        FROM Designation d where department is NULL or department=<deptInput>
    )a where priority = (
        select max( case 
            WHEN department=<deptInput> THEN 4 
            WHEN department is NULL AND DESIGNATION = "DIRECTOR" THEN 3 
            WHEN department is NULL AND DESIGNATION = "SENIOR" THEN 2
            WHEN department is NULL AND DESIGNATION = "JUNIOR" THEN 1
            ELSE 0 END
        )
        FROM Designation d where empName=a.empName GROUP BY empName
    )
)
```

The table structure cannot be modified.

Can anyone help simplify the query as I need to use this to query from Java. Or is there a simpler way to do the same in hibernate?

Comment: FYI : Sub-select statements in the `FROM` clause are not supported (only some ORM frameworks like EclipseLink in decent versions have a proprietary feature. Hibernate does not have nor it is a JPA standard as of now).

Comment: Hibernate will not make things simpler.  It just fits SQL better into an object-oriented framework.  I believe the Hibernate folks would tell you to do your object-oriented design first, and then build your table schema around that.  Since that's impossible for you, I wouldn't waste time looking for a Hibernate solution.

Comment: If you have to call it from Java, could you make it a Stored Procedure, optimize the heck out it, and call it using CallableStatement?